# Where to use ajax methods in testing? how to check where I can use them?

Tags: java, ajax, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new in automation and faced with ajax methods to click etc, but not clear where I can use them. Now if I cannot click on an element, I use ajax, but is there any way to see it on the page that I have to use ajax methods for specific elements?

```
 public void ajaxFocus() {
    JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    jse.executeScript("document.getElementById('elementid').focus();");
}


public void ajaxClick(WebElement element) {
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true)", element);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element));
    element.click();
}

public void ajaxClick(By by) {
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(by));
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(by));
    ajaxClick(driver.findElement(by));
}
```

I have those for now to test, but not sure where to use them. For now, as I understood I can use them when regular click methods are not working. Are there any exceptions to figure out that I have to use ajax methods?

Comment: AJAX: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp   The whole point of Selenium is to simulate the end user.  Do not use javascript to click links... the end user doesn't, and neither should you.  Some people do this to force their tests to pass, but really you should check your webdriver exceptions.  They are designed to be thrown for very specific reasons and, imo, should not be worked around.

Comment: also that function that scrolls the window first is not necessary.  A click action will scroll the element into view if needed.

Comment: Are you getting an error? What exactly are you asking?

Comment: I faced with the issue - to click the check boxes, and tried "action" "select" and other clicks, and after realized that I have to use ajax methods. Not sure how to figure out from exceptions to use them right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these methods as a backup when native webdriver functions do not work. WebDriver methods compare to js executor methods performs some actions before making a click, for example checking if element is visible, clickable, etc. You can find more information here - https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#element-click while js command does not. I use js commands sometimes when for example the opacity of the element is set to 0 and webdriver not able to click on it while js command works just fine